# Javascript Function: Use Variable instead of single Values

Tags: javascript, object

I found here a script. It works fine. But now, I want to use a Variable instead of single values.

Here the original script:

```
const customData = {
   "func":"bri",
   "oid":"ID",
   "onVal":1,
   "offVal":0,
   "...":"..."
}

const getSubset = (obj, ...keys) => keys.reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, [c]: obj[c] }), {});
const Light.bri = getSubset(customData, "oid", "onVal", "offVal");
```

Result (OK):

```
  bri: {
    offVal: 0,
    oid: "objekt-ID",
    onVal: 1
  },
```

Now I want to do define the keys in a variable, ideally as a object. But this do not work.

```
const params = {bri: "oid, onVal, offVal"};
const Light.bri = getSubset(customData, params.bri);
```

Result (NOK):

```
  bri: {
    oid, onVal, offVal: undefined
  },
  description: "Deckenspots"
}
```

what changes do I have to make?

Comment: `params.bri` is a string. Either change it to array of string or use `params.bri.split(',')`

Comment: Whatever "Result(NOK)" is supposed to be, it's invalid (3 brackets: `{ } }`). also, `description: "Deckenspots"` is nowhere but within said "Result(NOK)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `bri` property as an array of strings. That way you can use the [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to pass the strings as individual arguments.

```
const params = {bri: ["oid", "onVal", "offVal"]}; // bri is now an array.
const Light.bri = getSubset(customData, ...params.bri); // Notice the ... before params.bri
```